# How does the updating work on android applications SQLite

Tags: c#, android, mysql, sqlite

I have had a look online and some tutorials but i am struggling to understand the Sq lite stuff with updating users.

I will be making an android application in C# using xamarin and i need to have a database attached and the users will add to it with various bits of information. So from what i have researched you can use SQlite which is basically a database that's sort of within the application? not sure if that is correct. So should you use this over connection to MySQL remote database? is it even possible to connect to remote database?

Finally how does the updating work with android applications, does the users application update every time more information is added to the SQLite database, i cant imagine it does so how does it do it? i am just really confused on the subject at the minute and need some things clarifying.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlite is a database provider available on Android platform. You can use it store your applications private data, such as your user information.
It provides you all basic database functions required.

For help using sqlite in your application ref the android documentation

[Saving Data in SQL Databases](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

[Android data-storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

For an actual sample application using sqlite ref [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) blog [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com) blog post

If your database is going to be large and shared between multiple application users you should consider using a database server such as MySql or Postgres. For ref [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

In this case you will have to manage your database as well as the scripts required to interact with your database. Scripts may be in php or any other language of your choice. You will run a web server as well for the application to connect to, and your application should have access to internet.

Comment: Ah, i see, so i know PHP pretty well and since my application will be sharing data between all users then it makes sense to use MySQL.

Comment: Makes sense... then you go ahead with MySQL.